# Read data from Teradata in Execute SQL task in SSIS 2008

Tags: ssis, teradata

I am having a requirement to read a table from Teradata. Pull the records and send the email based on some condition. I have achieved this using Execute SQL task (which pulls me the data from Teradata) and For Loop Container (which send the email for every record).

I am currently using ADO.NET connection to connect to Teradata in Execute SQL task. The issue here is, I am not able to deploy this on SQL server. This package runs perfectly fine and the moment I run this from SQL Server agent, it fails with below error:

**"Executed as user: HNETNT\SQLDWDEV. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 10.50.4000.0 for 32-bit Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved. Started: 10:41:45 AM Error: 2014-09-19 10:41:46.27 Code: 0xC00291EC Source: Execute Query Execute SQL Task Description: Failed to acquire connection "Teradata Connection". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection. End Error DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1)."**

It looks like, I am using wrong connection manager, i.e. ADO.NET. Can someone please help me to make this work. I tried Microsoft Annuity driver, but this cannot be used in Execute SQL task. Also I tried using ODBC connection. This is also failing.

Comment: Are you using username/password authentication to connect to Teradata?

Comment: Yes. I am using my username and password to connect Teradata

Comment: Hum...I asked because I was wondering if you were encountering a Windows authentication issue--where the package was executed under the correct Windows account when run from VS but via a different account on the server. Since you're using a username & password, this wouldn't apply.

Comment: Is the username/password hard-coded into the package or is it set via configuration/parameters?